# Change tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm a bit confused on how I go about changing the UITableViewCell. Is this correct?

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
return 95;
}
```

If I need to explain more I can. Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm new to iOS dev.

Comment: wht do u want to change?

Comment: Explain it properly..what you want to change...this delegate is going to change the height of cell..

Comment: Thats exactly what I want to change.

Answer (score 1):

That code is fine, it is probably just not being called.  You need to properly set the `delegate` property of the table view for this method to be called.

**or**

Since your heights are all the same, you can take a shortcut and set the [rowHeight](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/rowHeight) property of your table view.

Comment: I think I'm calling the wrong delegate. This would be it, correct? @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView; I have that setup in my ViewControllor.h

Comment: *You* don't call the delegate.  `UITableView` does.  You only tell the table view which object implements the delegate methods.  If this is difficult to understand then you need to study Objective-C a little more before you continue because this pattern is used extremely often.

Comment: Ok, I'm about 99% positive I already have a delegate because I changed the separator colors. I apologize if I'm not making sense lol.

Comment: I don't think you know what a delegate is...does the term `UITableViewDelegate` mean something to you?

Comment: The worst thing you can do is just fumble around and hope that you get it right.  Start by googling "How to use UITableView" or something like that.  Keep looking until you understand my answer.  Until that point, you will not be able to make a good app.

Comment: Man, this was so helpful. I'm glad you told me to learn a bit more about delegates, solved my issue + I'm understanding iOS dev more and more!

Answer (score 0):

this delegate will change the height of the table view cell

Comment: r the delegates getting called

Comment: where ever u r initializing the table please set the delegate to self

Comment: This is my delegate correct? @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView; I have that setup in my ViewControllor.h.

Comment: and this is not the delegate this is a property u r setting

Comment: delegate is the method u wrote in ur question.Keep a breakpoint check if the breakpoint goes der

Comment: the delegate is right but only thing it is not getting called

Comment: No need to make it a strong property, since it is an IBOutlet object.  I'm certain it is already retained by being in the display hierarchy.

Comment: put tableview.delegate = self; in .m and in .h <uiTableviewdelegate , uitableviewdatasource>

Answer (score 0):

first check you have declared table view delegate in .h file or not..

No need of declaring table view with property..

```
UITableView *tableView;
```

declare like this..

Comment: @newbatcoding     just declare it like this in .h  ...    UITableView *tableView;

Answer (score 0):

set your table's datasource and delegate to File's owner from .xib.

[image]